# how to pass data using bundle in android?

Tags: android, fragment, bundle

I'm trying to pass parameters fragment to fragment(each in different activities)

```
 public class MainFragment1 extends Fragment {
        ListView dias;
        public SQLiteDatabase db;
        String label;
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            SQLiteHelper usdbh = new SQLiteHelper(getActivity(), "DBventas001", null, 1);
            db =usdbh.getWritableDatabase();
            dias=(ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.lv_dias);
            loadDias();
            dias.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    label = (String) (dias.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),label,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(), VentasActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("fechadiaventa",label);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }
public class VentasFragment1 extends Fragment {
    String recibido="";
    TextView tv_v1;
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        recibido= bundle.getString("fechadiaventa");
        tv_v1=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_ventas1);
        tv_v1.setText(recibido);
    }
```

log:

```
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at com.example.ventas.VentasFragment1.onActivityCreated(VentasFragment1.java:33)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1797)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:979)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at com.example.ventas.FragmentViewPagerAdapter2$MyPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentViewPagerAdapter2.java:76)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:869)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1019)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1473)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4876)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4876)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2423)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2011)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1250)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1425)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1143)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4667)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
08-11 13:23:02.859: E/AndroidRuntime(2270):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is line no 33 in VentasFragment1.java?

Comment: where I keep the parameter received

Comment: could you please specify the exact line..

Comment: Try `getIntent().getStringExtra("fechadiaventa")` instead of `bundle.getString("fechadiaventa");` in your code

Comment: recibido= bundle.getString("fechadiaventa");

Comment: yeah ok.. I understood.. please try replacing `getIntent().getStringExtra("fechadiaventa") ;` instead of `bundle.getString("fechadiaventa");`.

Comment: "The method getIntent() is undefined for the type VentasFragment1"

Comment: ok..if thats the case try `getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("fechadiaventa") ;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `Bundle bundle = getArguments();` as you havent set the arguments. Instead you just specified them as `Extras`.

Thus you should get the Extras in your fragment as below

```
recibido=getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("fechadiaventa") ;
```